# CSS - background image in the right padding

Tags: html, css

I have an `a` tag with right padding of 20px. How can I put just the right part of this image as background inside padding?

[image]

CSS rule for now:

```
.mali_oglas_kontrola a {padding-right: 20px }
.mali_oglas_kontrola a:first-of-type {background: url('../img/resursi/mgl_kontrola.png') no-repeat -17px 0;background-position: right top}
.mali_oglas_kontrola a:first-of-type:hover {background: url('../img/resursi/mgl_kontrola.png') no-repeat -17px -20px; background-position: right}
```

Comment: Basically you can't only show part of background image. So, there are several solutions: 1. As [Gaby suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11139644/620813), add another element inside that will show icon... 2. Alter your `sprite` image, add blank spaces around the icons (add enough blank space to cover the whole button, then position it accordingly. Note that for this to work you need to ensure the control maximum width (so that it does not run out of the blank space you added in a sprite).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not..

Insert another element inside your `a` tag that will hold the icon..

```
<a href="...">whatever <i></i></a>
```

and use

```
.mali_oglas_kontrola a i{
    display:inline-block;
    width:..;/*exact width of icon*/
    height:..;/*exact height of icon*/
    background: url('../img/resursi/mgl_kontrola.png') no-repeat right top;
}
.mali_oglas_kontrola a:hover i{
    background-position: right -20px;
}
```

Comment: Either that or alter the sprite to have some blank space around icons (filesize will not suffer much as you only add blank space)...

Comment: @poncha, that would only work if the blank space is guaranteed to be longer than the link's width.. (*is that what you meant ?*)

Comment: yep, thats exactly what i meant... PS why doesn't SO complete your name when i @ type it? ;)

Comment: @poncha, because the comment is in my own answer.. so i get notified for all comments regardless of whether my name is included or not..